# How do I format this hash?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, hash

I have a UUID with three unique properties for each UUID. I want to store all these. I know I need a hash inside a hash, but I  am having trouble doing this.

It's creating them inside a loop, and for each iteration I need to append/add it to the hash, so I'm not sure how to do that either.

```
19ee480015a2012f0aeb64ce8f2f69f4:
status: complete
name: SaveComment
pct_complete: 100 

083732301597012f0aea64ce8f2f69f4:
status: working
name: SaveComment
pct_complete: 35 

bf40ca301596012f0ae864ce8f2f69f4:
status: complete
name: SaveComment
pct_complete: 100
```

This is the code it's going into:

```
get '/percentcomplete' do
  progress = {}
  Resque::Status.status_ids.each do |uuid|
    active_status = Resque::Status.get(uuid)

    #update hash each loop here with name, status, pct_complete, and uuid
  end
end
```

Comment: So, what's the question?

Comment: how do i format the hash, like i dont know what goes inside of what. all i can think of is a hash is for something like a dictionary.. on the same level in the hierarchy. i also don't know how to add each new group to the hash in a loop so that it retains the {{uuid,this,that}{uuid,this,that}}

Comment: to clarify: i dont know how to tell it that each 'block' is its own part of the hash. I dont want just them all strung together like: uuid,this,that,uuid,this,that. I want them to be grouped, but still in the same hash. Furhter, i dont know how to append a hash.. i assume with merge, but i dont know if thats the best way. I tried concatenating an array and it didnt retain the groupins [[a,b],[a,b]]. I want to ultimately use a hash because its going to json, but i didnt even know how to get it to work with arrays

Comment: Why do you need a hash? Can you use a plain ol' Ruby object with some attributes?

Comment: edit: I added the code i'm using in above it that helps to make more sense

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming we can get name, status, pct_complete from active_status object,

```
get '/percentcomplete' do
  progress = {}
  Resque::Status.status_ids.each do |uuid|
    active_status = Resque::Status.get(uuid)

    #update hash each loop here with name, status, pct_complete, and uuid
    progress[uuid.to_s] = {:name => active_status.name, 
            :status => active_status.status, 
            :ptc_complete => active_status.ptc_complete}
  end
end
```

Comment: that was easier than i thought.. so really theres no add operator? You just overwrite the variable with a new key and it adds it?

Comment: There is a store method, to which we can pass key and value as arguments. You may have a look at http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-1.9.3/Hash.html for more details.